# 1 Object is linked to another Object though a third Object, how can I look up the third Object, based on knowing the 2 other Objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns, reference

I'm working in AS3 specifically but I feel that this is a pretty agnostic question.

Specifically I have sphere objects that can be linked to other sphere objects. They are linked though a third object. I would like to be able to look up the the linking object with only the knowledge of 2 sphere objects that are currently linked together. How would you approach this?

I would like to having to store a unique identifier string in each sphere object, just to avoid a global check to ensure that they are unique... but not opposed to the idea if it comes down to it.

----- solution ------

here is the solution I ended up with:

```
private function breakAtomicBonds( p_interactiveMatter:InteractiveMatter ):void
{
    var matchAmount:int;
    var key:Object;
    var atom:InteractiveMatter;
    var constraint:Constraint;
    var atoms:Vector.<InteractiveMatter>;
    var atomVOs:Vector.<InteractiveMatterVO>;
    var bond:InteractiveMatterVO;
    var bondIndex:int;
    var i:int;
    for( i = p_interactiveMatter.interactiveMatterVO.bonds.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) // each( bond in p_interactiveMatter.interactiveMatterVO.bonds )
    {
    bond = p_interactiveMatter.interactiveMatterVO.bonds[i];
    for( key in _constraints )
    {
        if( key is Constraint )
        {
            constraint = key as Constraint;
            atoms = _constraints[key] as Vector.<InteractiveMatter>;
            atomVOs = new Vector.<InteractiveMatterVO>;

            for each( atom in atoms )
            {
                atomVOs.push( atom.interactiveMatterVO );
            }

            matchAmount = 0;

            if( atomVOs.indexOf(p_interactiveMatter.interactiveMatterVO) != -1 )
            {
                matchAmount++;
            }

            if( atomVOs.indexOf( bond ) != -1 )
            {
                matchAmount++;
            }

            if( matchAmount == 2 )
            {
                trace( 'found constraint!' );
                _physicsWorld.removeConstraint( constraint );
                delete _constraints[constraint];

                for each(atom in atoms)
                {
                    bondIndex = atom.interactiveMatterVO.bonds.indexOf( bond )
                    if( bondIndex != -1 )
                    {
                        atom.interactiveMatterVO.bonds.splice( bondIndex, 1 ); 
                    }
                    bondIndex = atom.interactiveMatterVO.bonds.indexOf( p_interactiveMatter.interactiveMatterVO );
                    if( bondIndex != -1 )
                    {
                                    atom.interactiveMatterVO.bonds.splice( bondIndex, 1 );
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a dictionary with the joint object as the key, and it storing the 2 sphere objects it is connecting.

Answer (score 0):

For nodes & children, you could refer to the Composite Design Pattern

http://blog.createdbychristian.com/the-composite-design-pattern/